# Fixed background not working

Tags: css, background, attachment, fixed

I'm embedding the same CSS file on several webpages with the similar layout.

This works perfectly with all the webpages except one (http://1a23.com/green/wind.html).

```
body{  
    background: url('images/TextureBG.jpg') center fixed;  
}
```

In this page, the background can only be fitted in the first screen area, and rest of the background will remain white. When the webpage is re-rendered, (like resize the window, refresh, etc.) The background will be located to the current size of window, but other parts remains white.

This issue is tested on multiple computers with latest version of Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
body {
background: url('images/TextureBG.jpg') center repeat;
color: white;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
font-family: 'Helvetica', "Comic Sans MS";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of html errors, if you clean them up first it would be great so we know that no one of them are the cause of your problem.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F1a23.com%2Fgreen%2Fwind.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0